# jquery modal style - content overlay

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I asked the question yesterday and seemed to have it somewhat working however, when im clicking to show the content it appears then disappears as opposed to staying on the screen. here is the HTML:

```
<a href="" class="speclinkOpen">Show Spec</a>
<div class="speclink">   
    <h1>This is spec 1</h1>
    <a class="speclinkClose">Close</a>    
</div>

<a href="" class="speclinkOpen">Show Spec</a>
<div class="speclink">   
    <h1>This is spec 2</h1>
    <a class="speclinkClose">Close</a>    
</div>
```

the css:

```
  .speclink { 
    display:none; /* Hide the DIV */
    position:fixed;  
    _position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6 */  
    height:300px;  
    width:600px;  
    background:#FFFFFF;  
    left: 300px;
    top: 150px;
    z-index:100; /* Layering ( on-top of others), if you have lots of layers: I just maximized, you can change it yourself */
    margin-left: 15px;  

    /* additional features, can be omitted */
    border:2px solid #ff0000;      
    padding:15px;  
    font-size:15px;  
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ff0000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ff0000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ff0000;

}
.speclinkClose {
    font-size:20px;  
    line-height:15px;  
    right:5px;  
    top:5px;  
    position:absolute;  
    color:#6fa5e2;  
    font-weight:500;      
}
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function(){
$('a.speclinkOpen').on('click', function(){
$(this).next('div.speclink').css('display','block');
});
});
});
```

why does the content flash up rather than stay on the screen?

Comment: do not repeat document.ready statment twice...

Comment: if its so then what is `$(document).ready(function() { $(function(){`

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is simple.

`<a href=""` replace this with `<a href="#"`.

and you are done.

But its better to use some better modals like the [jquery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)
or [bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

Cheers!!